# how to implement gridview gallery with checkbox multiple selection in android

Tags: android

How to use gridview iwth text and multiple selection of checkbox with horizontalview in android like this images:

how to implement   gridview gallery with checkbox multiple selection in android
[image: image implementation pic]
how to use gridview iwth text and multiple selection of checkbox with horizontalview in android like this images
how to use gridview iwth text and multiple selection of checkbox with horizontalview in android like this images

[image: Images]

Comment: What you have tried show us.

Comment: i just use imgae gallery with check box to select text value with multiple selection and save in sqlite db....plz help i'm confused